# Is the "Loading from metro..." screen only for development, or can I remove it?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

I created a new app using `npx react-native init MyApp' which uses the default template. When I run the app both in the simulator and live on my device (iPhone), this happens:

1. Splash screen shows for a moment
2. "Loading from metro" screen shows for several seconds - overwriting my splash screen

[image]

3. Main app screen shows

My question is: does this metro screen only show for development and if I publish in the App Store it will not appear? Or is there a way to hide it and go direct from the splash to the main app screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metro screen only shows for debug builds. Make and run a Release build to run the app without the metro screen.

To make a Release build for ios:

To run release build in simulator:

```
npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release
```

To run release on phone:

1. In xcode Product menu > scheme > edit scheme
2. In sidebar click Run
3. Select build configuration: Release
4. Close dialog
5. Run using Product > Run (same as when testing)

Answer (score 1):

The screen is shown just in the development mode and won't be seen when you debug or release build your application, just try it by

**FOR ANDROID**

Step 1: Go to the root of the project in the terminal and run the below command:

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

Step 2: Go to android directory:

cd android

Step 3: Now in this android folder, run this command

./gradlew assembleDebug

There! you’ll find the apk file in the following path:
yourProject/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

Same goes for IOS too.